# label smoothing for inception v3 network

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

In [inception v3](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.00567v3.pdf) paper they discussed about `label smoothing` but in (keras code) [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-applications/blob/master/keras_applications/inception_v3.py]) there is nothing mention about label smoothing. How to write code for label smoothing for inception v3 network. It is suggested that it should be included in loss function. i am using `categorical crossentropy` loss function. So how to make custom `categorical crossentropy` for label smoothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a `label_smoothing` parameter to the function [CategoricalCrossentropy](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/CategoricalCrossentropy?version=stable) for label smoothing.

```
import tensorflow as tf

# when compiling the model
model.compile('sgd', loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(label_smoothing=0.1))
```